# Sum of infinite alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

The following sum has popped up during work within the theory Fourier series. I know the sum converges. What does is the value of this sum when found manually?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)^3}$$

Comment: If you mentioned  Fourier series, maybe you already know a function which has Fourier series with such coefficients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the Fourier series of $x^3$ on $(-\pi, \pi)$ is given by
\begin{align}
x^3=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{ \left( -1 \right) ^{n+1}{n}^{2}{\pi }^{2}+6\, \left( -1
 \right)^{n}}{{n}^{3}}} \sin{nx}. 
\end{align}

In particular, set $x=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$, we have that
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi^3}{8}=&\ 2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{ \left( -1 \right) ^{n+1}{n}^{2}{\pi }^{2}+6\, \left( -1
 \right)^{n}}{{n}^{3}}} \sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}}\\
=&\ 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty {\frac{ {(2k-1)}^{2}{\pi }^{2}-6}{(2k-1)^{3}}} \sin\left(\pi k-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\\
=&\ 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty {\frac{ {(2k-1)}^{2}{\pi }^{2}-6}{(2k-1)^{3}}} (-1)^{k-1}\\
=&\ 2\pi^2\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}-12\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)^3}.
\end{align}

Note that
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1} = \frac{\pi}{4} 
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
12\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)^3}= \frac{\pi^3}{2}-\frac{\pi^3}{8} \ \implies \ \ \sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k-1)^3}=\frac{1}{12}\frac{3\pi^3}{8}= \frac{\pi^3}{32}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for the deriviation. How would you go about showing that $$\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1} = \frac{\pi}{4} 
\end{align}?$$

Comment: This is Gregory series. There's a simple argument by considering a geometric series of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ then integrate and set $x=1$. This will yield $\pi/4$. However, the argument is not kosher since $x=1$ is on the radius of convergence. You will need a slightly modified argument. See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Gregory_Series.